# In github, how do i know when/how a merge is integrated to a gem?

Tags: ruby, git, version

I use the last version of the ruby Faker gem (1.1.2). It seems it does not integrate this merge :
https://github.com/stympy/faker/commit/e33484a531715937d8d4b520852f2029b9be83ff#commitcomment-3377208

How do you know the git commit version (is it how i call it?) that a gem uses.

How does the gem maintainers goes from a git commit to a gem available via bundler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in general - there is nothing in a gemspec that says what git commit a gem was built from.

It is often the case that the developer will create a git tag for each release, failing that the last commit before a release is usually one updating the version/changelog.